# How would I add a form to a page in Orchard Project?

Tags: orchardcms

I currently have a page within Orchard CMS, it only has content on it. The admin would like to add a form to this page.

So I would like:

- to have some content the admin will be able to manage on the right side.
- to add the form on the left side.
- visitors to have access to fill out the form and submit it.
- the form (stuff on the left) to be un-modifiable by the admin.

Is this possible out of the box? Is there an add-in or what would I need to write (module, widget, ...) to be able to split a page with a form on the left and content on the right?

```
        Page
*---------*------------*
*         *            * 
*         *   admin    * 
*         *  editable  *
*  form   *  content   *
*         *            *
*         *            * 
*---------*------------*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a [content part](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part) for the form piece to your problem. In the front end view .cshtml of the content part you can wrap the html in a

```
<div style=”width:50%; float:left;” />
```

Once the module is built and running Create a new Content Type that has all of the same parts as the page, but add your new form content part. Now when you create your new page you can wrap the body of the content in a

```
<div style=”width:50%; float:right;” />
```

This should drop both pieces into the article like so:

```
<article class=”content-item”>

    <div>form</div>

    <div>page copy</div>

</article>
```